# Downloading Photos from excel links

Tags: excel, vba

I have a massive excel file that has a huge amount of hyperlinks to images. My client would like these images in a zipped folder of course.

I have never touched VB code before so I have no idea what I'm doing. I have this, but I'm not really sure what to put into the 'range'...because again I have no experience with this. Some help would be appreciated. I keep getting 'runtime error 9'

```
 Option Explicit

Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Dim Ret As Long

'~~> This is where the images will be saved. Change as applicable
Const FolderName As String = "C:\Users\person\Desktop\images"

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim strPath As String

    '~~> Name of the sheet which has the list
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 4 To LastRow '<~~ 2 because row 1 has headers
        strPath = FolderName & ws.Range("A" & i).Value & ".jpg"

        Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, ws.Range("B" & i).Value, strPath, 0, 0)

        If Ret = 0 Then
            ws.Range("C" & i).Value = "File successfully downloaded"
        Else
            ws.Range("C" & i).Value = "Unable to download the file"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

and a sample of the kind of data. I'm just trying to pull the images out
[image]

Comment: The first thing that stands out to me is that you need a backslash separating your folder and filename: `strPath = FolderName & "\" & ws.Range("A" & i).Value & ".jpg"`

Comment: Why would I need the slash there? I'm honestly asking. I have no idea what I'm doing

Comment: Without it, your filename will concatenate with the word 'images'.

Comment: ok thank you! Do you have any idea why I'm getting the run time error? Like I said this is my very first time getting my hands on vb...I'm a front end developer.

Comment: Show a sample of the data you're working with.  If you're getting errors then indicate *which line* is highlighted when the error occurs and you hit "Debug"

Comment: You havent stated which line y ou get the error on yet.

Comment: No line is highlighted when I get the error. I will paste the error box I am getting above.

Comment: Renamed worksheet? Try `Worksheets(1)`instead of `Sheets("Sheet1")`. And press Debug in error message window!